# Download file associated to export button in webpage from terminal

Tags: python, r, bash, web, web-scraping

I would like to download the file that is produced by clicking on the "EXCEL Document" button in the bottom right of this page from the terminal.
Is it possible to do that from a unix bash?
Also within R or using python would be ok.

http://www.vivc.de/index.php?r=eva-analysis-mikrosatelliten-vivc%2Fresultmsatvar&EvaAnalysisMikrosatellitenVivcSearch%5Bleitname_list%5D=&EvaAnalysisMikrosatellitenVivcSearch%5Bleitname_list%5D%5B%5D=ABADI&EvaAnalysisMikrosatellitenVivcSearch%5BName_in_bibliography%5D=

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library may be what you're looking for.  You'd need the URL to pass in to `requests.get`

---

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://google.com')
r.raise_for_status() # Will error out if there's an issue with the get request
print(r.content)
```

outputs

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world\'s information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you\'re looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><scr...
```

Comment: Please see [answer].

Comment: @BenYarmis What URL should I pass to the function? The one associated with the button or the URL of the page, like www.vivc.de ?

Comment: @LiPaPe you would pass in the url associated with the button.  This site in particular, however, looks like it does some additional work after a popup is opened to get the file you want.